# Extracting Lambda Durations using CloudWatch metric filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

So I am using CloudWatch Metric Filters to try and extract the Duration of a lambda execution from the log group - however, I also want to match a specific string. For example

```
START RequestId: 75dc4985-08bb-467b-95c5-ddb6c122be30 Version: $LATEST

This is request type A

END RequestId: 75dc4985-08bb-467b-95c5-ddb6c122be30

REPORT RequestId: 75dc4985-08bb-467b-95c5-ddb6c122be30  Duration: 2004.33 ms    Billed Duration: 2100 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 55 MB  Init Duration: 122.53 ms
```

So in the example above, I would want to look for the string "This is request type A" and extract the "Duration" value for that specific request...if that makes sense

So essentially I want a way to monitor the duration for specific requests and I was hoping this was possible using filter patterns in the CloudWatch metrics.

If anyone has a suitable filter pattern that would achieve this, that would be great!

I stumbled across this article https://dev.to/frosnerd/monitoring-aws-lambda-functions-with-cloudwatch-1nap which has a useful pattern to extract the REPORT line from the logs. However, my situation is a bit more specific..

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Filter patterns apply only to single entries in the log, they do not work across records. For what you're describing you may want to look at using something like Elastic Search, or even some third party tools.

Comment: I can extract both values fine using ?"This is request type A" ?"Duration:" - I just need a way to work with the value of Duration - even an alarm that triggers when that string is found and the value of Duration is over x amount for example would suffice initially. Thank you though Jason.